# ActiveRecord race conditions in validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, concurrency

I'd like to clarify something about ActiveRecord. Say I have a scenario like this:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :song
end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases
  validate :cannot_update_if_being_sold

  def cannot_update_if_being_sold
    errors.add(:song, "Cannot update beats while beat is being sold.") if !self.purchases.empty?
  end
end
```

Now lets say I have an existing Song instance, and I try to update it. Isn't there a race condition here? Specifically:

1. Run song validations, everything passes
2. Create purchase for song and save to db
3. Save song to db

How can I prevent this from happening? I am not sure how to use locks in this scenario since purchases is a has_many.

Thanks!

Comment: What is a "race condition"?

Comment: A "race condition" is a circumstance in which two processes happen separately, and you get unpredicable results because you don't know which one will happen first.  I don't think this is an instance of race conditions though.

Comment: Can't a Purchase for this song happen after the Song validations pass and before the Song is actually updated in the DB? Specifically the value of self.purchases can change after it is called in the validation check. Right?

Comment: Actually yes, you're right:  if you have two seperate rails processes running, each accessing the same database (which you would probably have on your server) then an object could be rendered invalid inbetween being validated and being saved.

Comment: I'm sure you're aware that your "cannot_update_if_being_sold" condition is more like "cannot_update_if_has_ever_been_sold", btw :)

Comment: Could it be handled by callbacks? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: I think the same issue will exist.

Answer (score 0):

A purchase affects the Purchase model and updates on a song affect the Song model.
Since ActiveRecord maps these models to separate tables in the database, there is no 'race conditions' involved in accessing them separately.

However, I see if you were to DELETE a song, any purchases being made would throw errors.
Target that scenario and not the UPDATE one.

Also, but this should be standard, do not update the primary key for your songs.